# error in creating a scene

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am trying to create two scenes and add transition among them. But when i am initializing a scene by calling a method `Scene.getSceneForLayout()` runtime error occurs. Logcat error :
(Could not find method android.transition.Scene.getSceneForLayout, referenced from method com.example.practice.transition.Transition.onCreate
)
I following http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/scenes.html.

```
package com.example.practice.transition;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Fade;
import android.transition.Scene;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.practice.R;

public class Transition extends Activity {
  Scene a_scene,another_scene,ending_scene;
  ViewGroup root_scene;
  Fade fade_transition;
  Button fade_me;
  TransitionManager TM;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transition);

    root_scene = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scene_root);

    a_scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root_scene, R.layout.a_scene, this);
    another_scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root_scene, R.layout.another_scene , this);

    ending_scene=another_scene;
    fade_transition = new Fade(); 
  }
}
```

Here transition.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:id="@+id/master_layout"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_transition"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scene_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/a_scene" />
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fade_me"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fade Me" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

a_scene.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/scene_container">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

another_scene.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/scene_container">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 2"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_view2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat Error:

```
05-01 01:18:15.906: I/dalvikvm(31801): Could not find method                
android.transition.Scene.getSceneForLayout, referenced from method                 com.example.practice.transition.Transition.onCreate
05-01 01:18:15.906: W/dalvikvm(31801): VFY: unable to resolve static method 11314: Landroid/transition/Scene;.getSceneForLayout (Landroid/view/ViewGroup;ILandroid/content/Context;)Landroid/transition/Scene;
05-01 01:18:15.906: D/dalvikvm(31801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0018
05-01 01:18:15.906: D/dalvikvm(31801): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2c31 at 0x2f in Lcom/example/practice/transition/Transition;.onCreate
05-01 01:18:15.976: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(31801): Parent view is not a TextView
05-01 01:18:16.006: D/AndroidRuntime(31801): Shutting down VM
05-01 01:18:16.006: W/dalvikvm(31801): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416b3ac8)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.transition.Scene
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at com.example.practice.transition.Transition.onCreate(Transition.java:28)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-01 01:18:16.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31801):    at        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 01:23:24.597: I/Process(31801): Sending signal. PID: 31801 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Scene is available from API level 19 onward (Android 4.4); this looks like a crash from trying to use it on an older version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Scene a_scene,another_scene,ending_scene;
ViewGroup root_scene;
Fade fade_transition;
Button fade_me;
TransitionManager TM;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    root_scene = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scene_root);
    a_scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root_scene, R.layout.a_scene, this);
    another_scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root_scene, R.layout.another_scene , this);
    ending_scene=another_scene;
    fade_transition = new Fade();

}

public void doTransition(View v){
    Log.d("clicked", "clicked");
    TransitionManager.go(ending_scene, fade_transition);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/master_layout"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_transition"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scene_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/a_scene" />
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fade_me"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fade Me"
    android:onClick="doTransition"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

a_scene.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scene_container">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 2" />

</RelativeLayout>

enter code here
```

another_scene.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scene_container">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 2"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_view2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Line 1" />
</RelativeLayout>
enter code here
```

Comment: Please explain the changes you made and what your answer actually does compared to OP's question.

Comment: Doing transition is not the case. Error occurs when creating a scene and application crash . The error is at line(from logcat) : a_scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root_scene, R.layout.a_scene, this); But unable to solving it.